# How to view another class within a function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native and working to integrate Google Calendar API within my app. I have the API information in a separate JS file with a Calendar class extending a React component, and I'd like to call it within a function in my App.js

Here's my Calendar.js code:

```
import React from 'react';

var gapi = require('gapi');

export default class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            events: []
        };
        this.getEvents = this.getEvents.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getEvents()
    }

    getEvents() {
        function start() {
            gapi.client.init({
                'apiKey': 'APIKEY'
            }).then(function () {
                return gapi.client.request({
                    'path': `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${'CALENDAR'}/events`,
                })
            }).then((response) => {
                let events = response.result.items
                this.setState({
                    events
                }, () => {
                    console.log(this.state.events);
                })
            }, function (reason) {
                console.log(reason);
            });
        }
        gapi.load('client', start)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>{
                this.state.events.map(function (event) {
                    return (
                        { event: summary }
                    )
                })
            }</>
        )
    }
}
```

I've omitted the calendar and API key info for privacy reasons. Calendar API mostly taken from this walkthrough here: https://www.sivadass.in/using-google-calendar-api-with-react-js/

And here's my code for App.js -- I'm using a StackNavigator to move between different views / pages in the app. In particular, the Calendar API should appear when I go to the EventsCalendar page.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Linking, ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Calendar from './Calendar.js'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function WelcomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.biglogo} source={require('./images/large-white-bear.png')} />
      <Text style={styles.header}>Welcome to the {"\n"} My Test App</Text>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.iconcontainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('EventScreen') }}>
            <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('./images/calendar.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.icontext}>Event Calendar</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.iconcontainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('AnnouncementsScreen') }}>
            <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('./images/announcements.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.icontext}>Announcements</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.iconcontainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('AboutUsScreen') }}>
            <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('./images/aboutus.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.icontext}>About Us</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.iconcontainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('QuickLinksScreen') }}>
            <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('./images/quicklinks.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.icontext}>Quick Links</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
};

function EventScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('WelcomeScreen') }}>
        <Image style={styles.minilogo} source={require('./images/minibear.png')} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.subheader}>Event Calendar</Text>
      {/* I want to show my Google Calendar here */}
      <Calendar/>
      {/* I get an error here (see above for more details on error) */}
    </View>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="WelcomeScreen" component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="EventScreen" component={EventScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="AnnouncementsScreen" component={AnnouncementsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="AboutUsScreen" component={AboutUsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="QuickLinksScreen" component={QuickLinksScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#5683C7',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  biglogo: {
    height: 100,
    width: 200,
  },
  minilogo: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  backarrow: {
    height: 50,
    width: 40,
  },
  header: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: '500',
    padding: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  subheader: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: '500',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  iconcontainer: {
    height: 150,
    width: 180,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  icon: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: '#234579',
    borderWidth: 3,
  },
  icontext: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 20,
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: 15,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  body: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'justify',
    padding: 20,
  },
  underline: {
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 20,
    padding: 10,
  }
});
```

Right now, the error that appears when I navigate to the Event Calendar page says:

COMPONENT EXCEPTION. Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot tto export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of 'EventScreen'

But my EventScreen doesn't have a render method. I've tried adding it, using ReactDOM, and looking at methods employed in other StackOverflow questions, but I still can't seem to view my API properly. Again, any help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if you need more info. I also apologize if this looks really messy -- any advice for improving the cleanliness of my code would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've made `Calendar` the default export so you need to import it like `import Calendar from '...'` i.e. no brackets

Comment: Thank you! I'm now getting a different error for the render in Calendar, where in the first this.state.events.map line, it is saying 'can't find variable: state' but I thought it was already established in my constructor?

Comment: Try `this.state...`, you have a colon

Comment: I get a syntax error 'Unexpected keyword 'this' '. Thanks for your continued help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing your render function to something like this:

```
render(){
  return(
    <View>
      {this.state.events.map((event)=>{
        return(
          <View>{event.summary}</View>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey! So I've actually updated some of my code and got to the further error, which is 'Internal Error Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module 'gapi' from file ...' However the package itself specifies a 'main' module field that could not be resolved ... Indeed none of these files exist. I've updated my code to reflect the changes I've made!